# How do sandbar sessions work?

Tags: session, web-applications, clojure, compojure, ring

I'm supposed to use [sandbar](https://github.com/brentonashworth/sandbar) for a Clojure web application. I am wondering how sandbar maintains sessions on the server side? Does it us `jsessionid` cookies to identify user request? Or is sandbar just sending the session object back to the client, re-reading it from the request, manipulating the session and re-sending it back?

Answer (score 1):

sandbar sessions use the same storage backends that ring sessions use, and `wrap-stateful-session` supports the same options that ring's `wrap-session` uses. So you can use any session key you like (it's not `jsessionid` by default) and your preferred store. The default is an in-memory store.

Answer (score 1):

Each user gets a unique session ID, and that's all that's sent to the user in a cookie. Server-side, there's a mutable object mapping session IDs to objects - sandbar updates and reads from this based on the current session ID.